# ajax is not working in perl cgi script

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cgi

Hi i am trying to execute the ajax with with the cgi script and i am not sure this will work or not.I am trying to get the content from a file.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header(
        -type=> "text/html" );

print <<EOF;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"test1.txt",
             dataType:"text",
              success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
        }}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>

EOF
```

The same code with only html it is working perfectly but when i try with cgi it is not working.
I don't know is it correct way to write like this or not?

Please someone suggest me the correct way to make it working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue here is that when you call initially, if it is still `test1.txt` it will not be parsed as HTML by the browser. Also when you make the AJAX Call, you will want to only send back specific Text and not the HTML as well. Is the Ajax calling the script itself?

Comment: no..it is not calling

Comment: You may want to try using `$("#div1").load("test1.txt");` It would load the text right into the div.

Comment: Also, when you say it's not working, what do you see when you review the Source Code after loading the CGI?

Comment: again its not loading

Comment: So you get an error? Or you see no HTML?

Comment: i cant see anything on console...

Comment: I suspect that the CGI Script is not presenting the HTML to the Browser. Let me research this a bit, I don't work with CGI Scripts much, I do everything in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some research, you have print the `EOF`:

`print EOF;`

So the whole script would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = CGI->new;

print $cgi->header(
        -type=> "text/html" );

print <<EOF;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url:"test1.txt",
             dataType:"text",
              success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
        }}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
EOF

print EOF;
```

Example seen here: http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch6/text.html

Comment: we cant print like that...we can only print the file handle